# MPMoviePlayerController leaves App in incorrect orientation after fullscreen mode

Tags: ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

So we build an iPad App that only supports landscape orientation. This is enforced by setting the `Supported interface orientations (iPad)` to `Landscape (left/right home button)` in the plist. Also all the `UIViewControllers` have the implemented `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` as follows:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

This works fine and the App is locked in landscape orientation. Now we have a `MPMoviePlayerController` embedded in one of our views. When the user goes fullscreen with this movie, he is able to rotate to portrait. The movieplayer seems to bypass all our landscape settings. That's fine with me, but when the user taps the `done`-button when still in portrait orientation all our `UIViewControllers` are also in portrait and looking terrible!

The user has to rotate the iPad to landscape himself to make things look good again and will then be unable to rotate back to portrait as expected.

So why are my views rotated to portrait even when all `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` tell iOS to not rotate to portrait? And how can I make sure the movieplayer does not rotate my views?

If your solution also locks the movieplayer itself in landscape, that's fine with me. I'm happy as long as my views aren't rotated! :)

Comment: Have you tried subclassing MPMoviePlayerController and then overriding shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: so that it matches your other view controllers?

Comment: There is no `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` that will be called on the `MPMoviePlayerController` class. The `MPMoviePlayerViewController` has one, but overriding that one doesn't help. It seems not possible to force the movieplayer to landscape orientation.

Comment: I meant MPMovePlayerViewController. My fingers didn't get the message. MPMoviePlayerViewController inherits from UIViewController, and UIViewController does have a shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method, which you should be able to override in an subclass of MPMoviePlayerViewController. I don't have time to try it, but I think it's worth a try.

Comment: Did try that, but no result. The shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method isn't even called before rotating. If you could provide me with a working example that would be great!

Comment: When the view controller rotation methods don't get called, it usually means that the view controller controls a subview within the current view hierarchy, rather than the whole view hierarchy. I notice that you say, "[W]e have a MPMoviePlayerController embedded in one of our views." This might be the source of the problem. If I were you, I would instantiate a MPMoviePlayerViewController and then present it modally from within some other view controller. I wish I had time to craft a working example because this is an interesting question.

Comment: Yeah, well I can't present it modally, because the player starts embedded in a larger view. The rotation problems starts when the user taps the fullscreen-button in the embedden movieplayer to enlarge the video. Then he is able to rotate and none of the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: methods are called while fullscreen. So pushing it modal is not an option as I want to preserve the gapless playback while switching from and to fullscreen.

Comment: I did some poking around and found a couple of previous questions along the same lines as yours. (Search on "mpmovieplayercontroller rotation".) The solutions people have come up involve setting up an observer for the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification and then trying to force the app into the landscape orientation. The code is pretty ugly. As you probably know already, MPMoviePlayerController inherits directly from NSObject, and there's no obvious mechanism in the MPMoviePlayerController class for solving the problem. Obviously, the same is true of NSObject.

Comment: I am facing same problem in my one of the app.Could you please help how to fixed this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So why are my views rotated to portrait even when all shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation tell iOS to not rotate to portrait? And how can I make sure the movieplayer does not rotate my views?
>
> If your solution also locks the movieplayer itself in landscape, that's fine with me. As long as my views aren't rotated it's fine with me! :)

I had this exact problem when using this view hierarchy :

```
       +------------------------+  +-------------------+
       |                        |  |                   |
       | UINavigationController +->| Some Intermediate |
       |                        |  | View Controllers  |
       +------------------------+  |                   |
                                   +---------------+---+
                                                   |
                                                   v
                                          +--------------------------+
                                          |  MPMoviePlayerController |
                                          |       (embed)            |
                                          +--------------------------+
```

All of the Intermediate view controllers were locked to Landscape orientation so the App could never be in Portrait, except if the MPMoviePlayerController was in full screen (leading to the exact same problem as the OP).

The solution was to lock the **UINavigationController** to Landscape orientation by creating a subclass that overrides `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`. This way the MPMoviePlayerController no longer rotates to Portrait orientation. I suspect when entering fullscreen it adds itself to the rootViewController of the mainWindow, which in my case is the UINavigationController (or rather my subclass).

Hope this helps!